# Is URL-encoded form data required to be submitted in document order by user agents?

Tags: html, forms, url-encoding

When a user agent submits url-encoded form data, for example:

```
<form action="/someaction" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <p><label> Order: <input name="order" value="1" /></label></p>
    <p><label> Item: <input name="item" value="item 1" /></label></p>
    <p><label> Item: <input name="item" value="item 2" /></label></p>

    <p><label> Order: <input name="order" value="2" /></label></p>
    <p><label> Item: <input name="item" value="item 3" /></label></p>
    <p><label> Item: <input name="item" value="item 4"/>    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Is it required that the user agent, in general, send the data in document order?  Example:

```
order=1&item=item+1&item=item+2&order=2&item=item+3&item=item+4
```

I have looked at https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-urlencoded, and also read through https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/forms.html.  But, I am unable to find a definitive answer.

It would seem logical that data is submitted in document order, but perhaps it is not required?

Answer (score 1):

The resource handling the `POST` request is not aware of the order in the form submitting to it. Therefore it can't know which order would be the correct one and therefore this simply doesn't matter.

Comment: I have additional bindings defined outside the form containing this information - these are on the server and not visible to the rendered page.

Comment: If you defined an order somewhere and enforce it, that's on your side. But in every environment I've seen the order never mattered because the POST data was parsed to a map anyway.

Answer (score 1):

After further investigation, it seems the answer is yes -

the [construction of the entry list](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#constructing-entry-list) is performed in [tree order](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-tree-order).